# "where "condition with DateType or Timestamp in spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to do conditions like `df = df.where("dateColumn <= 1950")` with the format of datetype or timestamp in PySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the SQL [`year`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/sql/index.html#year) (or Pyspark API [`year`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.year)) function:

```py
df = df.where("year(dateColumn) <= 1950")

## OR


from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.where(F.year(F.col("dateColumn")) <= 1950)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implicitly extract the [year](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.year.html) and filter

```
df.filter(F.year(F.col('dateColumn')) <= 1950)
```